# MySQL Table empty even though it has been filled in via Python

Tags: python, mysql

I wrote a python script to populate a MySQL table via excel data. 
At the end of the Python Script I print out the content of the table:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Cities")

rows=mycursor.fetchall()

for r in rows:
    print r
```

and I get the proper results returned:

```
(1, u'Muenchen', 2.0, 3.32, 1, 1)
(2, u'Augsburg', 0.7, 1.008, 1, 1)
(3, u'Frankfurt', 1.1, 1.694, 1, 2)
(4, u'Wiesbaden', 0.3, 0.405, 1, 2)
```

But when I open the table via MySQL Workbench, it's empty. Via the regular terminal I get the same results:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Cities;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `COMMIT` changes

> [MySQLConnection.commit() Method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html)
>
> This method sends a COMMIT statement to the MySQL server, committing the current transaction. Since by default Connector/Python does not autocommit, **it is important to call this method after every transaction that modifies data for tables that use transactional storage engines.**

```
>>> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO employees (first_name) VALUES (%s)", ('Jane'))
>>> cnx.commit()
>>> cnx.close()
```

Comment: Also, don't forget to close the connection with 'cnx.close()'.

Comment: I assume the cnx is a typo and means cnt, which would come from something like
cnt=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root")?

Comment: @cheesus Yes, it is for connection. Name of course should match the one that you are using :)